# I'm getting this error Deprecated: "Required parameter $field follows optional parameter $post_id" with a number of item like this one

Tags: wordpress-theming

The website had been sitting for a while. I login and update the site. The homepage went blank. I set debug and get this error.

Deprecated: Required parameter $field follows optional parameter $post_id in /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-listing/includes/extensions/advanced-custom-fields/plugin/includes/acf-value-functions.php on line 54

Deprecated: Required parameter $field follows optional parameter $value in /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-listing/includes/extensions/advanced-custom-fields/plugin/includes/acf-value-functions.php on line 166

Deprecated: Required parameter $value follows optional parameter $key in /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-listing/includes/extensions/advanced-custom-fields/plugin/includes/ajax/class-acf-ajax.php on line 76

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Elementor\Scheme_Typography" not found in /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-listing/includes/elementor/elementor.php:393 Stack trace: #0 /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): MyListing\Elementor\Elementor->load_custom_fonts() #1 /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #2 /home/johnson/web/hfyc.hereforyoucentral.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action() #

I change php version from 7.4 to 8.0.  But changing it now does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters should not come before required parameters.
Try to find the function signature and change its parameters order.

e.g.:

`function foo($post_id = 0, $field)`

should become

`function foo($field, $post_id = 0)`

Ref.: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.deprecated.php